# Visual Web Developer 2008 won't auto generate classes from Linq

Tags: linq-to-sql, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer, auto-generate

I'm new to Linq and Visual web developer 2008 Express.  I have read some posts here and Scott Guthrie's on setting up Linq, but I'm a little stuck because the classes aren't auto-generating as I thought they would.  I have setup a database with a simple table (with the Primary Key as the ID, and it is set to auto-increment) plus a few other columns, and dragged and dropped it on to the DBML Linq designer pane.  The table appears in the window, but no classes are auto-generated.  When I right click on the table and select "View Code", `DataClasses.cs` is displayed, but I only see a partial class with no methods or properties.

Isn't Linq supposed to do this, or have I (quite likely) missed the point completely?  Or is this functionality not available in Visual Web Developer 2008 Express?

Comment: I'm sure he meant that. Retagged.

Comment: So, @Hewie, what you do now is upvote all the answers that helped you and accept one of them that solved your problem. To upvote, hit the up arrow above the number to the left of each answer.  (Just a little SO culture introduction.  Welcome aboard).

Comment: Thanks.  I ticked the reponse but can't upvote because I don't have enough rep yet :(  Oh well, thanks though :)

Comment: There's 10 more.  That'll help.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not missing anything.  That is exactly how it should work.  Go to solution explorer, expand the dbml, and double-click on whatever.designer.cs.  Down at the bottom, you'll see ...

```
[Table(Name="dbo.YourTable")]
public partial class YourTable: INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);
```

... and all of your properties.

Comment: Thank you - everything is there :)

Answer (score 1):

As the other answerers have already pointed out, you do get your code generated - into a single (modelname).designer.cs file.

This may or may not be what you expected and wanted - if you can live with it - perfect!

If not, there's at least one set of Code generation templates out there called [PLINQO](http://www.plinqo.com) which are based on CodeSmith, the well known code generator. Those templates allow you to do a lot of things standard Linq-to-SQL doesn't support:

- generate classes for each table into their own, single file in a user-definable folder
- actually **update** your DBML model and all associated generated classes if the underlying database changes
- adds a "(entityname)Manager" class to manage entities of a given type (like Customer etc.)

All in all, it's quite a neat solution to handle Linq-to-SQL code generation. Excellent stuff - recommended!

Marc

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, LINQ-To-SQL will not actually generate individual class files for you - if you go and write some code that references a class for one of your tables, you will find that it is there...

Comment: Thanks - I expected to see a stack of class files generated, but I can see that the classes are accessible anyway :)